# How to write the lowest 24 bits unit?

Tags: go

```
// vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2:

package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "encoding/binary"
)

func main() {
    x := uint32(1)
    err := binary.Write(os.Stdout, binary.LittleEndian, x)
    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
}
```

I can write 32 bits by `binary.Write` by the above code. If I want to write the lowest 24bits of uint32, can I do it with `binary.Write`. Or I'd better extract each lowest 8 bits and write them as byte array?

```
$ go run main.go | xxd
00000000: 0100 0000                                ....
```

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. What's your larger goal here? To write a sequence of numbers capped at 24 bits to a io.Writer?

Comment: maybe create your own type type int24 int32 and implement your own io.Reader for this type?

Comment: @colm.anseo Could you provide the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this two ways:

- generic inline; or
- custom type

---

**Generic**

Leverage the native `Write` method of any `io.Writer` like `os.Stdout`:

```
w := os.Stdout      // any io.Writer
x := uint32(197121) // any bit-shift capable type, uint64 etc.

// little-endian order
w.Write([]byte{
    byte(x),
    byte(x >> 8),
    byte(x >> 16),
})
```

https://play.golang.org/p/9WSUpX8zYcw

```sh
go run ./main.go | xxd
00000000: 0102 03
```

---

**Custom Type**

define a custom type & method and match the [io.WriterTo](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#WriterTo) interface:

```
type int24 int32

func (x int24) WriteTo(w io.Writer) (int64, error) {
        n, err := w.Write([]byte{
                byte(x),
                byte(x >> 8),
                byte(x >> 16),
        })
        return int64(n), err
}
```

To use:

```
for _, v := range []int24{
    197121, // 01 02 03
    513,    // 01 02 00
    1,      // 01 00 00
} {
    v.WriteTo(os.Stdout)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/IdfM6s_Ytpn

```sh
% go run ./custom.go |xxd
00000000: 0102 0301 0200 0100 00
```

Comment: This should probably be an [`io.WriterTo`](https://pkg.go.dev/io/?tab=doc#WriterTo), both for naming convention, and error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know go but one way to do this is to AND the dest int32 with FF000000 and then OR with the source int24. Could be faster like this

Comment: That certain does obtain the lower bits needed. But the OP was asking how to efficiently write this to an `io.Writer`. There exists binary encoders to do this for all the standard types (`int32`, `int64` etc.) but not for custom types - hence the need to write your own encoder.